# Jquery Hide Show Does Not Seem To Be Working Correclty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a *div* like this:

```
<div class="box-body">
   <a href="#" id="hideshow">Hide</a></br>
   <div id="message">
      <p>password: <input type="password" name="blog_pass"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what I want to do is to hide the div `message` when I click on the `hideshow` link and show it again when I click on this link again.

So I added a script at the end of my page in order to do this:

```
$('#hideshow').toggle(function(){
    $('#hideshow').text('Show');
    $('#message').hide();
}, function(){
    $('#hideshow').text('Hide');
    $('#message').show();
});
```

But now the problem is it does not even work out. I mean no error appears on console and even the link `Hide` is not showing somehow.

So what is your idea about this... How can I fix this?

Comment: [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). You don't need to use this: $('#message').hide(); so remove hide and show function.

Comment: You're wrong. You should use like : `toggle(duration, function) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class say, `hidePwd` to toggle it for hide/show operation:

```js
$('#hideshow').click(function(){
    var newText = $('#hideshow').text().trim() === 'Hide'? 'Show':'Hide';
    $('#hideshow').text(newText);
    $('#message').toggle('hidePwd');
});
```

```css
.hidePwd{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
   <a href="#" id="hideshow">Hide</a><br>
   <div id="message">
      <p>password: <input type="password" name="blog_pass"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another duplicate

Comment: @satpal feel free to vote to close as dup